# rxjava use result of single in observable

Tags: java, observable

I have an Observable with items of a certain type A. For every item that the observable pushes I would like to lookup a relevant object of type B from a repository/datastore that returns it as Single.

What is the correct way of doing this?

I already tried to do it by using the blockingGet() methode and it works but I don't know if this is the right/correct way.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<A> items = Arrays.asList(new A(), new A(), new A());

    Observable.fromIterable(items)
            .map(a -> {
                //This could be coming from a repo/datastore/something else
                B b = getRelevantB(a).blockingGet();

                //do stuff with a & b;
                a.doStuff(b);
                return a;
            })
            .subscribe();
}

//not actual implementation but just to sketch a situation
public static Single<B> getRelevantB(A a) {
    return Single.just(new B());
}

public static class A {

    public void doStuff(B b) {
        //stub
    }
}

public static class B {
}
```